# Referencing a variable from constructor function using prototype

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, prototype

I am new to OOP Javascript and am trying to gain understanding on how it works by creating a simple effect. The issue I am encountering is that I cannot seem to reference variables from the constructor function inside an prototype transition function. Any help on this would be great. Thanks.

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KkHfB/3/)**

```
function AniSize( ele, nH, nW ) {
    this.element = ele;
    var origWidth = ele.width(),
    origHeight = ele.height(),
    newHeight = nH,
    newWidth = nW;
}

AniSize.prototype.transition = function() {
    this.element.hover(function() {
        $(this).animate({
            width: newWidth, // error: newWidth is not defined
            height: newHeight // error: newHeight is not defined
        });
    }, function() {
        $(this).animate({
            width: origWidth, // error: origWidth is not defined
            height: origHeight // error: origHeight is not defined
        });
    });
};

var box = new AniSize( $('div#box'), 200, 200 );
box.transition();
```

Comment: `var` declares a local variable, that won't be available outside of the `AniSize` scope, you need to attach them to `this`.

Comment: functions defined on the `.prototype` play by all the same rules of variable scope. No magic I'm afraid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`var` declares a local variable, that won't be available outside of the `AniSize` scope, you need to attach them to `this` so you can access them in the prototype. Then you'll have to cache `this` so you can reference those variables inside the extra scope that the event is creating:

```
function AniSize( ele, nH, nW ) {
    this.element = ele;
    this.origWidth = ele.width();
    // same with the others...
}

AniSize.prototype.transition = function() {
    var self = this; // cache `this`

    this.element.hover(function() {
        $(this).animate({
            width: self.newWidth,
            height: self.newHeight
        });
    }, function() {
        $(this).animate({
            width: self.origWidth,
            height: self.origHeight
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: I wonder why a method named `transition` is binding handlers. I've got a feeling that OP wants to bind in the constructor, and trigger in `transition`. Just a thought. ...+1 though.

Comment: @CrazyTrain: Yeah, I guess the structure could be better, I would probably create an `init` method and attach the events in there.

Comment: I have updated the  **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KkHfB/8/)** but its not working... & yes I should have created a better name. This is just for testing purpose.

Comment: Mmmm, you forgot `var self = this;`. That's half the answer. http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/KkHfB/9/